# Unwanted column is part of index in generated DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created Web API core project and generated entity framework core related components as detailed in the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

It generated all the entities properly, but few indexes were created with an extra column. Here is an example

```
entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Column1, e.Column2, e.Column3 })
                    .HasName("ix_Table1_Column2_Column3");
```

In the above example, column1 is not actually part of index when i checked DB directly. I am puzzled as to what is causing this issue.

This presence of unwanted column is causing below exception.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The indexes {'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'}
>   on 'Table1' and {'Column2', 'Column3'} on 'Table1' are both mapped to
>   'able1.IX_Column2_Column2' but with different columns ({'Column1',
>   'Column2', 'Column3'} and {'Column2', 'Column3'}).

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: EF Core much "smarter" that EF6 about indexes. For example it does not generate separate index for FK column if you have index with multiple columns where this FK is first one. Maybe your case also related to this "smart" features (or bug in it). Can you show full entity class and it index-key configuration, please?